# How many functions are there from $A$ to $B$ that send $3$ elements in $A$ to a specific element in $B$?

Tags: combinatorics, functions, discrete-mathematics

Let $A$ and $B$ be sets such that $|A|=m$ and $|B|=k$. Fix $b \in B$. We would like to know how many functions there are from $A$ to $B$ such that at least $3$ elements in $A$ map to $b$.

Initially, I thought that it was $\binom{m}{3}k^{m-3}$, by first picking three elements in $A$ and mapping them to $b$, then randomly mapping the remaining elements in $A$, but I have noticed that this is overcounting and I'm not sure how to fix this.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Do you need exactly 3 elements or at least 3 elements? Your title suggests exactly and the question suggests at least.

Comment: You are correct, I mean at least $3$ elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number that send exactly $r$ elements to $b$ is ${m\choose r}(m-r)^{k-1}$, so you want $\sum_{r=3}^m{m\choose r}(m-r)^{k-1}$. Whether there is a simpler form, I know not.